# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'epoch' - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, attributeerror

I huild an auto encoder in keras following steps given in a simple autoencoder based on a fully-connected layer (https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)

```
wiki_autoencoder.fit(wiki_train, wiki_train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(wiki_test, wiki_test))
```

After training and cross vaidation. plotting the results gives me error given below:

```
    loss = wiki_autoencoder.history.history['loss']
    val_loss = wiki_autoencoder.history.history['val_loss']
    epochs = range(epochs)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
    plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
    plt.title('Training and validation loss')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-6acdd795daf3> in <module>()
      1 loss = wiki_autoencoder.history.history['loss']
      2 val_loss = wiki_autoencoder.history.history['val_loss']
----> 3 epochs = range(epochs)
      4 plt.figure()
      5 plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')

NameError: name 'epochs' is not defined
```

The second thing i tried gives be result : No handles with labels found to put in legend. however plot is generated. how do i solve this problem

[image]

```
plt.plot(wiki_autoencoder.history.history['val_loss'], 'r', wiki_autoencoder.history.history['loss'], 'bo')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define range properly as epochs is not defined which you used inside range(). You can use any other number apart from 100 depending on your requirement.

```
epochs = range(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually find epochs from history object.

```
epochs = wiki_autoencoder.history.epoch
```

This will give you the epochs for which the model was trained.